# Skip creating file in FileOutputStream when there is no data in Inputstream

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

This is a logging function which logs error stream from the execution of an external program. Everything works fine. But I do not want to generate the log file when there is no data in error stream. Currently it is creating zero size file. Please help.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(logFile);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(externalProgram);

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line=null;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   if (pw != null){
      pw.println(line);
      pw.flush(); 
   }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply defer the creating of the `FileOutputStream` and `PrintWriter` until you need it:

```
PrintWriter pw = null;

Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(externalProgram);

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   if (pw == null)
   {
      pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(logFile));
   }
   pw.println(line);
   pw.flush(); 
}
```

Personally I'm not a big fan of `PrintWriter` - the fact that it just swallows all exceptions concerns me. I'd also use `OutputStreamWriter` so that you can explicitly specify the encoding. Anyway, that's aside from the real question here.

Comment: Thanks @Jon Skeet. I found my mistake. I tried to defer only the PrintWriter, because FileOutputStream is actually is a parameter of the function. Looks like I need to change my parameter type to File then create FileOutputStream inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing to do is to change

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(logFile);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
....
   if (pw != null){
   ...
   }
```

to

```
FileOutputStream rawLog = null;
try {
    PrintWriter Log = null;
    ....
       if (log == null) {
           rawLog = new FileOutputStream(logFile);
           log = new PrintWriter(log, "UTF-8");
       }
       ...
} finally {
    // Thou shalt close thy resources.
    // Icky null check - might want to split this using the Execute Around idiom.
    if (rawLog != null) {
        rawLog.close();
    }
}
```